# Subset dataframe based on rule - sequence

Tags: r, date, dataframe, weekday

Subset dataframe w/ sequence of observations

I am experimenting with a large dataset. I would like to subset this data frame, in intervals of Monday through Friday. However, I see that some weeks have missing days (Thursday is missing one week).

If one sequence of days, i.e. Monday to Friday, I would like to not include this sequence of days in my sample.

Would this be possible?

```
week.nr <- data$week.nr[1:20]
week.day<- data$week.day[1:20]

date <- data$specific.date[1:20]

price <- data$price[1:20]

data.frame(date,week.nr,week.day,price)


data.frame(date,week.nr,week.day,price)
         date week.nr  week.day price

1  2019-01-28      05    Monday  62.6
2  2019-01-25      04    Friday  63.8
3  2019-01-24      04  Thursday  64.2
4  2019-01-23      04 Wednesday  64.0
5  2019-01-22      04   Tuesday  64.0
6  2019-01-21      04    Monday  63.4
7  2019-01-18      03    Friday  62.6
8  2019-01-17      03  Thursday  62.6
9  2019-01-16      03 Wednesday  64.0
10 2019-01-15      03   Tuesday  64.4
11 2019-01-14      03    Monday  65.2
12 2019-01-11      02    Friday  66.4
13 2019-01-10      02  Thursday  66.2
14 2019-01-09      02 Wednesday  68.2
15 2019-01-08      02   Tuesday  68.8
16 2019-01-07      02    Monday  67.8
17 2019-01-04      01    Friday  67.4
18 2019-01-03      01  Thursday  68.0
19 2019-01-02      01 Wednesday  69.6
20 2018-12-28      52    Friday  71.0
```

Comment: Group by week number and year, then check if each group has 5 days of the week, then filter if n is not 5.

Comment: Take into account that for @zx8754  solution to work fine, your dataset must only have  intervals of Monday through Friday and not days duplicated!

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to illustrate how?